# How to query across three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a WorkSpace, Project, User, and Membership models. A user has many memberships, and many projects through memberships. A project belongs to a work space.

Getting the users projects is pretty easy:

```
user.projects
```

But reaching across to get the work spaces is tricky. Something like this raises an error of `undefined method spaces for collection proxy`.

```
user.projects.work_spaces.unique
```

How can I get a unique set of work spaces that the user is involved in? (Work Spaces with projects that the user belongs to through memberships).

Comment: `user.projects.map(&:work_spaces).flatten.uniq` will return all the work_spaces linked to the user through the projects relation (the uniq will remove duplicated objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ActiveRecord, I would suggest leveraging its association methods in order to avoid the verbose code and poorer performance of .collect(&:work_spaces).flatten.uniq.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :projects, through: :memberships
  has_many :work_spaces, through: :projects
end
```

You will then be able to ask for `user.work_spaces`.

Answer (score 1):

`user.projects` is a collection of projects, which is why you can't call `work_spaces` directly on it.

You can use Enumerable's `collect` method (or `map`) to grab all the collections, then strip out the duplicates:

```
user.projects.collect(&:work_spaces).flatten.uniq
```

Comment: why not `Enumerable#flat_map` ? :) i.e. `user.projects.flat_map(&:work_spaces).uniq`

Comment: At the very least, make sure to do `user.projects.includes(:work_spaces).collect(&:work_spaces).flatten` to guarantee that you're not incurring N+1 ActiveRecord queries to get all the WorkSpaces.