# Setting up and querying ActiveRecords associations between THREE models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I'm a newly-minted Rails "Developer" and this is my first StackOverflow question (yay!). I'm building an app (for my class final project) that allows users to earn points from predicting activities and events on a given TV show. Having fun so far but am, however, having trouble building the best way to define associations between the below models.

I've researched three-way associations between three models, but most answers (like [How to query across three models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196347/how-to-query-across-three-models) and [Right association between three models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819722/right-association-between-three-models) ) don't address HABTM associations between *all three models* ... So your help would be greatly appreciated!

### An overview of my issue:

A show consists of many ***episodes***, and there are many ***contestants*** (characters) on each show. By association through show, contestants and episodes should have a HABTM relationship, but I don't need that segment for my app...

The tricky part is that each ***contestant*** can score many ***points*** on a given ***episode***. What I would like to do is to record the points each contestant earned per episode, then query this later when I need to calculate points for the users.

I've experimented with a joined table **contestants_points** with an attribute of **episode_id** as the third column, but that didn't work. I've also toyed with the idea of a table **contestants_episodes_points** but couldn't figure out how I could create a new instance for that table. Here's my attempt on structuring the models below:

**contestant.rb**

```
class Contestant < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :show
    has_and_belongs_to_many :points, inverse_of: :contestants
    has_many :episodes, through: :points                         # not sure about this
end
```

Example: contestant 1 = { name: 'Gloria', age: 30, occupation: 'Nurse, show_id: 1 }

**episode.rb**

```
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :show
    has_and_belongs_to_many :points, inverse_of: :episodes
    has_many :contestants, through: :points                    # not sure about this
end
```

Example: episode 1 = { show_id: 1, air_date:2014/04/02 }

**point.rb**

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :show
    has_and_belongs_to_many :contestants, inverse_of: :points
    before_destroy { contestants.clear }
    has_and_belongs_to_many :episodes, inverse_of: :points    
end
```

Example: point 1 = { event: 'Contestant gets in an argument', show_id: 1, points: 10 }

Example: point 2 = { event: 'Contestant gets eliminated on episode 7', show_id: 1, points: 70 }

### The big puzzle:

How should I set up associations between all three models so that I could query:

- How many points did Contestant A scored during Episode 1?
- Which contestants scored points during Episode 1?
- How many points did Contestant A score between Episodes 1-5?

Is HABTM the right approach to get the query results I want? Is there a simpler way to structure these three models? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails has\_many :through sum attribute on "child objects" --> SQL Toughy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052191/rails-has-many-through-sum-attribute-on-child-objects-sql-toughy)

Comment: Thanks, Brad. The above answer will certainly help me with querying once I get my models nicely set up, but it's not clear to me how I should structure my models and associations... will keep researching tho!

Comment: You should post solution as an answer, rather than appending it to your question (and then accept an answer once the timeout has passed rather than adding "solved" to the question)

Comment: Thanks @FrederickCheung for that note, I've updated per your suggestion. This is my first time posting so your best-practice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am going through the very episode -> contestant -> points example to make the answer short and clear.

First some advice: Whenever you have any trouble dealing with activerecords, jump to the `rails console`.

Now you have mentioned, **Contestant** `belongs_to :show` also **Episode** `belongs_to :show`.

To support these relations, you must have `show_id` present in both `contestants` and `episodes` table. That's how rails maintains the association. So everytime you create a contestant or episode, you will also pass the show id with them.

Lets say show id is 1.
then,

```
show = Show.find 1
```

Now to access all the contestants or episodes for that show:

```
show.contestants 
# => returns all contestants for show 1
show.episodes
# => returns all episodes for show 1
```

Now back to your question:

> The tricky part is that each contestant can score many points on a
>   given episode. What I would like to do is to record the points each
>   contestant earned per episode, then query this later when I need to
>   calculate points for the users.

If I am correct, points are scored by the contestant. So your relation is incorrect there:
point `belongs_to :contenstant`.

Moving forward, as points belongs to contestants, in your `points` tables there will be contestant_id column, again that's how relation are maintained.

So lets create a contestant.

```
contestant = Contestant.create(name, attributes, show_id, episode_id) # as episode has many contestant 
# => returns contestant
```

Now create episode

```
episode = Episode.create(name, attributes, show_id)
# => returns episode
```

To view all contestants of the episode:

```
episode.contestants
```

creating points for contestants:

```
point = Point.create(value, contestant_id)
```

accessing points of contestant

```
contenstant.points
```

Now going back from point.

```
point.contestant
#=> returns contestant to whom it belong

point.contestant.episode 
#=> returns episode in which it was scored

point.contestant.show 
#=> returns the show that point belongs to
```

PS: Its a long answer, so even though i tried to stay focused I may have got lost in-between, if so ask I'll clarify that particular thing.

Comment: Thank you @shivam! One problem I'm seeing here is that a contestant can be on/have many episodes, but I'm playing around with your suggested structure. I'm playing around with it now, will let you know where I get stuck at!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an episode to have many points through the contestants on that episode.

The contestants have points and the episodes have contestants. The way to get from an episode to the number of points for that episode is through the contestants.

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

## Current Solution

A brilliant classmate of mine suggest I view points as instances of events and rename the Point class to ***Event***, then create new ***Point*** class with attributes  **contestant_id, episode_id** and **event_id**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :franchise, inverse_of: :events
    has_many :points
    has_many :contestants, through: :points
    has_many :episodes, through: :points
end

class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :contestant
    belongs_to :episode
    belongs_to :event
end
```

Now I can run the below query in the console:

```
> Contestant.first.points
=> # [Point1, Point2, Point3]
> Contestant.first.events
=> # [Event1, Event2, Event3]
```

Now I can access the actual point assignment with ease. Very easy re-structuring with minimal updates to my other 10 models. Thank you Allen Hsu!